# Controller action not working with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, controller

I have setup user authentication with Devise and created a show action in the users_controller and routes as follows:

```
#users_controller.rb
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

#routes.rb
match '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', via: 'get'
```

What I want to do then is link to the user who is currently logged in (the users profile), which I tried with:

```
%li= link_to "Profile", @user.id
```

but it doesn't seem to work quite the way I want it to. I also tried current_user, which I assumed was the standard helper method for Devise.

How can I get the link to the user profile to work?

P.S. Before you ask: The show template is created and in the appropriate direction.

Comment: How is it working right now and how does this differ from what you want?

Comment: When trying to access the user (e.g. users/1) it throws: undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: @Severin, check my update below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did u try

```
%li= link_to "Profile", users_show_path(@user.id)
```

to get the path check

```
rake routes
```

EDIT:

do this

modify your route

```
match '/users/:id', to: 'users#show', via: 'get', as: "users"
```

then

```
%li= link_to "Profile", users_path(current_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
%li= link_to "Profile",user_path(current_user))
```

Answer (score 0):

In routes

```
resources :users
```

In view

```
%li= link_to "Profile", user_path(@user)
```